Is the concept of "Strong dollar/Weak dollar" a cycle?
I am trying to understand the reasoning of "strong dollar/weak dollar",

Weak Dollar: Leads to increased exports due to cheaper prices for foreign buyers.


Increased exports boost dollar value.

So, basically, we have -- weak dollar --> increased export --> strengthening dollar.
What is wrong with this reasoning?
